# WordPress after_password_reset not firing

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to ping an API when a user has reset their password, but it seems like the after_password_reset is not firing at all.

Here is my code:

```
function password_change($user, $new_pass) {  

    error_log('hello there');

    $req_string = "https://example.com/example.php?action=password&username=$user&password=$new_pass";
    $request = wp_remote_get($req_string);
 
}

add_action('after_password_reset', 'password_change', 10, 1);
```

After the password is reset the system seems to immediately redirect and login without actually firing after_password_reset.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Is your WP version quite old, perhaps? According to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218224, it was introduced in WP 4.4.

Comment: I am running WP 5.8, thank you though

Comment: Do you at least get to see your error_log output anywhere then? (And have you first of all made sure, that actually writes to a file on the server, and not just into the output buffer?)

Comment: What’s the purpose of calling this API anyway, and why does it get the user’s password passed as a parameter (apparently without even any encryption)? I think that sounds quite shady to begin with. Is this some sort of internal API, or are you actually sending _my_ password to an external service?

Comment: It's for an SSO (single sign-on) system. All accounts for one site need to be mirrored on the others. They all use different databases so I have no choice other than to make an API call. This is a prototype, I won't be sending plaintext passwords in production.

Comment: There's no error_log, which is what leads me to believe it's not even firing. Error logging is working fine in other functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235831/discussion-between-tmo-and-cbroe).

Comment: Did you try changing the priority of add_action to 1 ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. I've run a full hook/filter log and the after_password_reset is not recorded.

Comment: Is the add_action code being run? Is the file included?

Comment: Yes, it's in a custom plugin which is running other hooks/functions without issue.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this? I am in the same situation. The hook `password_reset` gets fired, but not `after_password_reset`